# ffmpeg--chrome could not load mp4 after server processed

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I'm using C# to write the server-side along with ffmpeg to deal with some video files.After I load the video file from client and write the stream to a new file, I couldn't use ffmpeg to extract some part of the original file, code like below

```
string cmd = "-ss " + string.Format("{0:F}", startTime) + " -t " + string.Format("{0:F}", endTime - startTime) + " -i " + filePath + " -vcodec copy -acodec copy " + filePath + " -y";
```

it shows the error [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002336e7da340] stream 1, offset 0x8fab: partial file;Invalid data found when processing input

after investigated, I found that the file which I mentioned as filePath(server side) maybe occupied by windows command(I used the Process to deal with ffmpeg)

```
Process myPro = new Process();
        myPro.StartInfo.FileName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FFMPEGPath"];
        myPro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myPro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        myPro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myPro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        myPro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myPro.Start();
        myPro.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
        myPro.WaitForExit();
        myPro.Close();
        myPro.Dispose();
        return output;
```

I decided to create a new file to perform the extract operation and it works.

```
string cmd = "-ss " + string.Format("{0:F}", startTime) + " -t " + string.Format("{0:F}", endTime - startTime) + 
" -i " + filePath + " -vcodec copy -acodec copy " + filePathfull + " -y";
```

But when I tried to post back the file name by ajax to client and use video tag in html, it couldn't load the mp4 file, I think, maybe the mp4 file which generated by ffmpeg is still occupied by system thread, have you ever met such situation? How could it been fixed? thanks a lot!

Comment: I've tried to put some mp4 files on server NOT processed by ffmpeg and they worked properly, the root cause must be related with ffmpeg and windows command

Comment: by the way, I can open the mp4 file processed by ffmpeg on server, the file is properly generated, and I can delete it or rename it